# ios, scrolling screen with a few objects without zooming

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, scroll

I have screen w/ a few labels. Each of them might be from 1 to a dozen lines.
So some times all content not to fit on screen so scrolling is necessary.

All seem to be easy and there are a lot of tutorials how to do it.
But my problem that scrolling works only when I zoom in screen. Setting "contentSize" doesn't give any effect.

```
@interface OMSScroolViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@end
```

and implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    scroll.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
    scroll.maximumZoomScale=1.0;
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1690)]; // constants for simplicity
    scroll.delegate=self;
}
```

any suggestions?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Curious...shouldn't the implementation code be, for example, `[self.scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1690)];` (with `self`)?

Answer (score 0):

Although not technically required, I've never had UIScrollView to work properly without using a content view to wrap the scrollable content. Once you wrap all your labels in a single view, your code should work without issue.

Comment: Ok. I add one more property UIView. It has the same size as ScroolView (occupied all space). Labels are inside this containerView. Nothing changed. 
**'property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;'**