# ios, scrolling screen with a few objects without zooming. Attempt 2

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, scroll

@everybody
Hi guys!

I've not found out the solution to my problem, so I decide to ask the question again.
First attempt is there [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277025/ios-scrolling-screen-with-a-few-objects-without-zooming)

I have screen w/ a few labels. Each of them might be from 1 to a dozen lines. So some times all content not to fit on screen so scrolling is necessary.

All seem to be easy and there are a lot of tutorials how to do it. Just set **contentSize** bigger than **frame**. But my problem that scrolling works only when I zoom in screen. Setting **contentSize** doesn't give any effect.

```
@interface OMSScroolViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@end
```

and implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    scroll.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
    scroll.maximumZoomScale=1.0;
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1690)]; // constants for simplicity
    scroll.delegate=self;
}
```

I've also tried to use a extra UIView inside UIScroolView but w/o any success.
Moreover I found a few threads there on stackoverflow w/ the same problem, unfortunately w/o solutions.

Thanks for cooperation.

Comment: Hmmm, you shouldn't post the same question twice. If it is not getting enough attention, you can place a bounty, or edit it so it gets moved to the top of the Active Question list.

Comment: @CaptJak Ok. I'll take it in to account. Thanks.

Comment: @LargeGlasses
LargeGlasses, thanks man!!!
The solution is 

    - (void) **viewDidLayoutSubviews**
    {
        [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
        [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1690)];
    }

retrieved from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077367/why-wont-uiscrollview-scroll-fully-after-adding-objects-using-storyboard-arc?rq=1